# Global Variables in SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following code in VBA:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE Workstations SET MID = newvalue WHERE MID = tempvalue"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

newvalue and tempvalue are both global variables and have already been set values. Syntax wise, does this make sense? or am I missing quotation marks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one:

If `MID` is *number*:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE Workstations SET [MID] = " & newvalue & " WHERE [MID] = " & tempvalue
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

If `MID` is *string* (if `newvalue`/`tempvalue` doesn't contain single quote `'`):

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE Workstations SET [MID] = '" & newvalue & "' WHERE [MID] = '" & tempvalue & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

If `MID` is *string* (if `newvalue`/`tempvalue` contains single quote `'` like `newvalue="Mike's car"`):

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE Workstations SET [MID] = '" & Replace(newvalue, "'", "''") & "' WHERE [MID] = '" & Replace(tempvalue, "'", "''") & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

If `MID` is *date*:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE Workstations SET [MID] = #" & newvalue & "# WHERE [MID] = #" & tempvalue & "#"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Thanks to @HansUp for pointing out in comments, that

> MID is the name of a function, so it would be safer to bracket or alias that field name in the SQL statement: SET [MID]

Comment: `MID` is the name of a function, so it would be safer to bracket or alias that field name in the SQL statement: `SET [MID]` and `WHERE [MID]`  Better yet, rename the field with a name which is not a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).

Comment: Thanks, @HansUp, that make sence. Updated my answer.

Comment: What's going to happen if `newvalue` or `tempvalue` are strings with single quotes?  You should also escape them, or better, switch to parameterized statements.

Comment: thank you so much! really went in depth here. I probably should have specified MID is a number field. Thanks again!

Comment: Rather than bracketing fields / columns, it is best to prefix with an alias `UPDATE Workstations w SET w.MID `, this scales nicely to other servers and you need never worry about reserved words again.