# Data type mismatch Acess 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get a Data type mismatch error when I try to run the following code:

```
Dim myString As String
Dim rs As Recordset

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE KLIST = " & Me.bleh
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
myString = rs.Fields("DATEK")
```

The "bleh" field is a normal text field in a form. The field "KLIST" in the "KLIST" table is also a text field, containing numbers.

Does the fact that i enter numbers in the text field in the form change the format of the field? And if it does, how can I compare them in the WHERE statement.

Thanks.

Comment: try this one `sSQL = "SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE KLIST = '" & Me.bleh & "'"`

Comment: The format error disappeared, but now it says that there is no such record. I double checked and there is such record. Is it possible that I will get the ASCII code of the number, but not the number itself as a string(text)?

Comment: I don't think so, I've just tested with number and it works for me. Check whether your filed in table (or `Me.bleh`) contains additional spaces (trailing or leading)

Comment: At the KLIST field there is a set Field size of 8. Maybe this is the problem. Still cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: try to run this SQL statement in query designer: `SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE TRIM(KLIST) = 'x'` where `x` is value of `Me.bleh`. Does it retrives your records?

Comment: and also try this one in VBA: `sSQL = "SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE TRIM(KLIST) = '" & TRIM(Me.bleh) & "'"`

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint on the `Set rs = ...` line and type `?sSSQL`<enter> in the direct window (open with Ctrl-G). This will show you the resulting SQL statement. Copy this one to Query window (in SQL mode).

Comment: The TRIM helped, Thanks!

Comment: Just 1 more thing, How can I access the KLIST.dbf, if it is not in the current database. Cant seem to find the right way to specify the path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE TRIM(KLIST) = '" & TRIM(Me.bleh) & "'"
```

also you may want to see this on how to use VBA variables in SQL statements for different data types: [Global Variables in SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563844/global-variables-in-sql-statement/22563897#22563897)

Answer (score 0):

If `KLIST` is a text column, you must add string delimiters (single quotes in SQL):

```sql
SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE KLIST = '123'
```

In VBA

```vb
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE KLIST = '" & Me.bleh & "'"
```

---

A single quote within a string in SQL can be escaped by doubling the quote:

```sql
SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE KLIST = 'that''s it'
```

Use the `Replace` function in VBA to achieve this:

```vb
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM KLIST WHERE KLIST = '" & Replace(Me.bleh, "'", "''") & "'"
```