# Using a global var in an SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access project in wich I use a global variable across all the forms to show what user is logged in.

```
Public activeUser As String
```

On one of the forms I want show data depending on who is logged in. there are several fields on the form, so I want to use a query as data source across the whole form.

Now here is my problem:

I tried to make a query that uses the value in `activeUser` to look up all the values that the active user should be able to see:

```
SELECT WBS_Id, 
       Verantw, 
       Commentaar 
  FROM tbl_New_WPE_User 
 WHERE UserName LIKE activeUser
```

Why does this not work? and How can I make it work?

Comment: you may want to check this link: [Global Variables in SQL statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563844/global-variables-in-sql-statement/22563897#22563897)

Comment: I would strongly recommend avoiding global variables where possible. They are cleared on any unhandled error. Why not store the user in a local table?

Comment: @Remou Isn't it bad practise to use tables for stuff like that?

Comment: @Gutanoth For a user name? Why would it be bad practice?

Comment: @Remou I was once told that I should avoid  "hard" tables in a database as much as possible (only use "temp" query tables when I need them")

Comment: A database is all tables! What difference if you have a small table with certain information? It would be faster than a UDF and available outside MS Access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to create a VBA function to return the value of the global variable. For example

```vbs
Public Function GetActiveUser() As String
    GetActiveUser = activeUser
End Function
```

Then you could use the function in a saved query like

```sql
SELECT WBS_Id, 
       Verantw, 
       Commentaar 
FROM tbl_New_WPE_User 
WHERE UserName LIKE GetActiveUser()
```

However, in this particular case I would be inclined to get rid of the global variable and just call the function to get the current user (i.e., the code you used to populate the global variable). I doubt that the extra overhead of retrieving the value each time (e.g., by getting the `.Username` property from a `WScript.Network` object) would amount to very much, and if it did turn out to be an issue then you could always consider using a `Static` variable inside your function to cache the value.

Comment: Looks good, but why Like? Would that not be unsafe? Gord, GordT etc?

Comment: @Remou Good question. I really didn't pay much attention to the SQL code itself, I was focused on replacing the global variable with the function. Still, LIKE without wildcards acts the same as `=`, so I think it would only return an exact match.

Comment: Rhetorical question :) I still think Like is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

i guess SQL is written in VBA code in form of string:

```
Public activeUser As String
dim tmpSql As String

tmpSql = "SELECT WBS_Id, Verantw, Commentaar FROM tbl_New_WPE_User WHERE UserName LIKE activeUser"
```

if so, then you should do the following:

```
tmpSql = "SELECT WBS_Id, Verantw, Commentaar FROM tbl_New_WPE_User WHERE UserName LIKE " & activeUser & "*"
```

where `*` in Access is the equivalent for `%` in SQL Server

Now, if the SQL statement is written in an Access Query, then it's not possible to use VBA variable `activeUser`