# Data type mismatch on SQL Query in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to do an SQL query in VBA to retun a specific case number. Whenever I execute the query, it returns an error of "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression". I am passing the query an integer to use to query an autonumber primary key.

```
    Dim c As ADODB.Connection
    Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String, strManager As String
    Set c = New ADODB.Connection
    c.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Commit Tracker.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM CommitTrk WHERE CASE_ID_NBR = '" & CInt(frmCommitViewer.lstCases.Value) & "'"
    Set r = c.Execute(strSQL)
```

Of course the debug hilights the execute command. Any help would be appreciated. Am I passing the wrong datatype to match the autonumber? If so, what datatype should I be using? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `CASE_ID_NBR` has numeric type, you should use it without quotes:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM CommitTrk WHERE CASE_ID_NBR = " & CInt(frmCommitViewer.lstCases.Value)
```

you may also want to read this: [Global Variables in SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563844/global-variables-in-sql-statement/22563897#22563897)

Comment: Perfect, that worked. I am still trying to wrap my head around this SQL thing. The formatting is throwing me off. I will accept the answer when it allows me to. I will read that in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: in general it's common mistake when to use `"SELECT ... WHERE Field1 = 1"` (numeric) `"SELECT ... WHERE Field1 = #01/01/2012#"` (dates) and `"SELECT ... WHERE Field1 = 'sometext'"` (text)