# Delete table in access with String with 3 values

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Good day,

Im getting an error (syntax error missing operator in a query expression for "and monitorNumber = Monit)

```
SQLDel = "DELETE FROM HBAU WHERE Peoplesoft ID ='" & PSID & "' and DATE =#" & InputDate & "# and MonitorNumber = Monit"
```

can anyone tell me whats missing...

Comment: oh nevermind i found it. was suppose to be RcdSet1.Open "DELETE FROM HBAU WHERE PeoplesoftID =" & PSID & " and DATE =#" & InputDate & "# and MonitorNumber =  " & Monit & ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Monit` is VBA variable, try this one:

```
SQLDel = "DELETE FROM HBAU WHERE [PeoplesoftID] =" & PSID & " and [DATE] =#" & InputDate & "# and [MonitorNumber] = " & Monit
```

also should `Peoplesoft ID` be `PeoplesoftID`? Note if your `PeoplesoftID` has numeric type, you don't need single quotes around `PSID`.

Aslo you may want to read this: [Global Variables in SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563844/global-variables-in-sql-statement/22563897#22563897)